# Access a Windows dll from Java under Linux (probably through Wine)

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface, wine, winelib

I've managed to run JavaFX 2.0 under Linux by following [this guide](http://andre86blog.blogspot.com/search/label/javafx). It works nicely by running a Windows version of Java using Wine. This Java process can pick up the native .dll files of the Windows version of JavaFX.

Now I wonder if there is a different solution that runs a Linux version of Java but somehow makes access to the .dll files through Wine.

To sum it up graphically:

- **works:** Wine -> Java(win) -> DLL(win)
- **what I'm asking:** Java(linux) -> Wine -> DLL(win)

### Why I want to do it

I have the hope to make the application start like any other Java application and only require an installation of Wine. The already working solution requires a Wine installation *and* a Windows version of Java.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt wine makes `.dll` appear as `.so` Wine works by creating an emulated environment and applications have to be run inside that environment to work.

What you should be able to do is

```
Java(linux) -- socket --> Java(Wine) -- loads --> DLL(win)
```

Comment: This still requires the Windows version of Java. But it's a good idea.

Comment: You may be able to reduce the duplication between the two versions.

Comment: This approach would work even if the DLL has to be run in virtual machine running windows or another box running windows. It means your main JVM can be 64-bit making use of a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: In my case the .dll will produce GUI stuff and use the GPU. So it should execute on the machine running the application. Concerning your first comment: Do you know where I can read up how to strip down the Windows JRE to use it with Wine and the Linux JRE?

Comment: I was thinking of finding the files which are the same and using symbolic links or hard links.  There are tools for finding duplicate files. e.g. many of the jars should be the same or could be made the same.

Comment: This http://doubles.sourceforge.net/ tool finds duplicates are creates links for example.